# chroot heredoc terminates early for specific package

Tags: bash, debian, chroot

Something interesting and a bit beyond my understanding here. I can run these commands against a Debian Buster chroot without issue. This is handy for me to run multiple commands in a chroot with a single input stream.

```
# Ex1. This works fine and prints "hi"
chroot LIVE_BOOT/chroot/ /bin/bash <<EOF
false
bad_command
echo "hi"
EOF

# Ex2. This *also* works fine and prints "hi!"
chroot LIVE_BOOT/chroot/ /bin/bash <<EOF
apt install -y --no-install-recommends nano
echo "hi!"
EOF
```

But something about *this* specific package causes the script to abort early so that following commands do not run.

```
# This runs the apt command fine, but then stops executing.
chroot LIVE_BOOT/chroot/ /bin/bash <<EOF
apt install -y --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg-core
echo "hi????"
EOF
```

I have a hunch it has something to do with the fact that that `xserver-xorg-core` invokes `keyboard-configuration`, but that's a wild guess.

```
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Configuring keyboard-configuration
```

Whatever the reason, the `apt` install for `xserver-xorg-core` completes fine, but the heredoc terminates immediately after and I don't know why or how I could fix it. Is this an oddity around `chroot` or the distro I'm using? Do I need a special `/dev` or `/proc` mount for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to solve it by turning off the interactive frontend:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: You are correct! I forgot to translate that from Docker and I wasn't paying close enough attention. The script failed, but `xserver-xorg-core` was installed so I assumed it was fine. It must've been hung up on the user input. Thank you!

Comment: If that solves it, please consider accepting the answer. Glad it helped!